# $watch vs ng-if performance

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get information about performance in an AngularJS application. I wonder if there is any performance difference between using `$watch` or `ng-if`, as we can use one or the other to obtain the same result/behavior.

Note that I'm using `$watch` **only to check if the data is loaded**. The directive doesn't need to watch for future data changes

As an example let's say we have a *controller* that retrieves data from an Ajax request and a *directive* that needs this data.

### Using `$watch`

**The controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(   
    'MyController',
            ['$scope',  'MyService',
                function ($scope , MyService) {

                    $scope.myObj = {}

                    // http request
                    MyService.getData( function (result) {
                        $scope.myObj.myData = result
                    })
                }
            ]
);
```

**The directive**

```
  angular.module('app').directive(
       'myCustomDirective',
       [ function () {

       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           scope : {
               data : '='  // the data provided by the MyController
           },
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                // watching changes on data
                var myWatcher = $scope.$watch(data, function(value) {
                   if(value) {
                       // do something with data    

                       myWatcher(); //kill watcher
                   }
                });
           },

           templateUrl: '/myTemplate.html'
       };
   }]);
```

**HTML file**

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <my-custom-directive data="myObj.myData"></my-custom-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Using `ng-if`

**The controller (no changes)**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller( 
    'MyController',
            ['$scope',  'MyService',
                function ($scope , MyService) {

                    $scope.myObj.myData = {}

                    // http request
                    MyService.getData( function (result) {
                        $scope.myObj.myData = result
                    })
                }
            ]
);
```

**The directive (removing $watch)**

```
  angular.module('app').directive(
       'myCustomDirective',
       [ function () {

       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           scope : {
               data : '='
           },
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
               // do something width data   
           },

           templateUrl: '/myTemplate.html'
       };
   }]);
```

**HTML file (adding `ng-if` directive)**

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-if="myObj.myData">
        <my-custom-directive data="myObj.myData"></my-custom-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there any difference in terms of performance?
2. As it is demanding on term of memory/performance, is there another/better way to avoid using $watches in that particular case (*inside directive to watch a controller's $scope*)?

Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it what you're trying to achieve here. `ngIf` is a directive that watches an expression to either render an element or not. While `watcher` is a listener function to watch an expression and do specific operation. They both are fired in every `$digest` cycle which starts from `$rootScope` and then its children. Maybe you can explain more what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think you should know the difference between the `ng-if `and `$watch`

Comment: I think the code is pretty clear and show what I'm trying to do. Isn't it ?

Comment: Actually my question is, why you want to use `$watch` in directive?

Comment: @Merlin I am sorry, I failed to understand what you're trying to do in your code. But yeah, your code is clear. Please rephrase it by answering Ramesh's question. Why?

Comment: I did it this way when I started to learn Angular and now I'm wondering if its better to use `ng-if`. So you say it is better to use `ng-if`  english is not my native language ?

Comment: @Merlin Better to use `ng-if` for what?

Comment: @choz to be sure `myDirective` has access to `data`as I only need to know if the data is loaded

Comment: @Merlin If you just need to know the data is loaded, and want to render an element, you want to use `ngIf`. Otherwise if you need to use the data in the controller or directive if the data is loaded, you need to setup a `wathcer`.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f4fb6e0983a6a700dc4a246a913504550b55f1e9/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js

> > $scope.$watch($attr.ngIf, function ngIfWatchAction(value) ....

So ng-if uses $watch, most angular directives does. So there is no real difference.

But there is no sense in creating directive that does something already implememnted. So in general it is better to use angular built-in directives, if you need something new - do not afraid to use $watch.

Comment: Then in my case (the code provided) should I use `$watch` or `ng-if` ? Is it an advantage to use `$watch` as I can kill ?

Comment: In this particular example, ngIf is better, of course. But this is not about performance, but style.

Comment: The `ng-if` directive creates a new child scope which uses prototypical inheritance. So in addition to adding a watch, it adds that additional overhead.

Comment: ng-if never creates scope.